# Looping through xmlnodes using Xdocument

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml string like this

```
<Test>
  <ConnectionParameters>
   <ConnectionParameter DisplayName="asd" Id="cgfh" IsPassword="false" IsRequired="true">   </ConnectionParameter>
   <ConnectionParameter DisplayName="asdasd" Id="fgh" IsPassword="false" IsRequired="true"></ConnectionParameter>
    <ConnectionParameter DisplayName="asdasd" Id="hdfh" IsPassword="false" IsRequired="true"></ConnectionParameter>
   <ConnectionParameter DisplayName="asdad" Id="dfgdf" IsPassword="false" IsRequired="true">  </ConnectionParameter>
 </ConnectionParameters>
</Test>
```

How can I loop through each "ConnectionParameter" tag inorder to get the attributes like Id,DisplayName etc using xdocument?

I tried like this,

```
 XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
    xdoc= XDocument.Parse(fileContent);
    var saveResult = from b in xdoc.Descendants("ConnectionParameters")
                     select new
                     {
                         success = (string)b.Element("ConnectionParameter").Attribute("Id").Value ?? string.Empty,
                     };
```

But it only returns the first node only

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Hint: look at the `Element()`, `Elements()` and `Descendants()` methods.) There are various ways of doing this depending on whether you want to validate the parent element names as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently looping through all the `ConnectionParameters` elements (of which there's only one) and selecting the first `ConnectionParameter` element (using the `Element` call). You want to just loop through the `ConnectionParameter` elements:

```
// Note the lack of creating a new XDocument for no reason
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(fileContent);
var saveResult = from b in xdoc.Descendants("ConnectionParameter")
                 select new
                 {
                     success = (string) b.Attribute("Id") ?? ""
                 };
```

Or to avoid creating an anonymous type for no obvious reason, and using plain "dot notation" as the query expression isn't helping you much:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(fileContent);
var saveResult = xdoc.Descendants("ConnectionParameter")
                     .Select(b => (string) b.Attribute("Id") ?? "");
```

If you prefer to make the parent element names explicit, you could use:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(fileContent);
var saveResult = xdoc.Element("Test")
                     .Element("ConnectionParameters")
                     .Descendants("ConnectionParameter")
                     .Select(b => (string) b.Attribute("Id") ?? "");
```

Or:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(fileContent);
var saveResult = xdoc.Root
                     .Element("ConnectionParameters")
                     .Descendants("ConnectionParameter")
                     .Select(b => (string) b.Attribute("Id") ?? "");
```

Comment: is it possible to specify the parent name in the above code?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi: Added two options for that.

Answer (score 1):

Load your xml into xDocument, then you can do something like this (can't remember exact syntax) 
`xDoc.Root.Descendants("ConnectionParameters").Attribute("DisplayName").Value;`